# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/vfs/FileSelector

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, kettle

I'm trying to call my Java method which is written using Kettle Pentaho jars.
while calling its throwing an error like this...

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path
>   [/sakti-backup-restore] threw exception [Handler processing failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/vfs/FileSelector] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSelector
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.di.core.KettleClientEnvironment.init(KettleClientEnvironment.java:65)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment.init(KettleEnvironment.java:89)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment.init(KettleEnvironment.java:65)
>     at
>   com.htc.sakti.restore.backup.etl.DynamicETL.buildCopyTable(DynamicETL.java:36)
>     at
>   com.htc.sakti.restore.backup.controller.RestoreAndBackupController.bakcupDB(RestoreAndBackupController.java:816)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Any solutions?

Comment: What is the specific Java code that produces this error?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like `commons-vfs` is missing from your classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```